# NoSuchMethodError returned when using BIRT 3.7 with Grails 2.5

Tags: grails, birt

We have been using BIRT 3.7 in a Grails app for 3 years. We decided to upgrade from Grails 2.3.11 to 2.5 and our BIRT report now bombs with this error:

```
SEVERE: Error happened while running the report.  
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.data.ExpressionParserUtility.parse(ExpressionParserUtility.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.data.ExpressionParserUtility.compileColumnExpression(ExpressionParserUtility.java:77)
.....
```

I am assuming that something was changed in Grails. This report worked fine in Grails 2.3.11.

Comment: When you upgrade grails it's often necessary to upgrade the plugins as well. I recommend upgrading to birt 4.3.0. And go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Turns out it was not a BIRT/Grails issue. It was a BIRT/Asset issue.

Comment: Glad you solved it @DennLindy but how??!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the following line in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
compile ":asset-pipeline:2.3.9"
```

To this:

```
compile(":asset-pipeline:2.3.9") {
    excludes 'rhino'
}
```